# onclick of particular li set property only to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-toggle clickme');
a.setAttribute('href', '#');
a.innerHTML = name[n]      // Group Name

var span = document.createElement('span'); // Tick sign on li
span.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-check pull-right');
span.setAttribute('style', 'padding:5px;border: 1px solid rgba(120,120,120,0.9);border-radius:3px;color:pink;');
//   span.setAttribute('id', name[n]);
a.appendChild(span);
```

Here in `ul`, I am dynamically adding `li` and also adding a tick sign to it when user clicks on it (it will have a green tick sign).

```
$('span').on('click', function (e) {
    $('span').css('color', 'green');
});
```

but it adds the CSS `color` property to all `li` whereas I want it applied only for the particular `li` on which user clicked. Any idea please?

Comment: Have you tried using `$(this)` instead of `$('span')`?

Comment: @Harry thnx for ur help..its working..one more question plz..all li is dynamically generated if in ul all li is marked as a green then that ul will be green automatically ..how to do that?

Comment: A bit more description on *ul will be green* will be helpful. If all `li` is already green, I don't see much value add in adding the property again to the `ul`. Furthermore the next addition of your dynamic `li` could again result in not all `li` having green color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jquery**

```
$('span').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

> `$('span')` inside click function will select all the span elements but when u use `$(this)` it selects the particular element for which the click function is done

Comment: @Harry i am on my way typing it harry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').on('click', function (e) {
    $(e.target).css('color', 'green');
});
```

Comment: what does  $(e.target) do?

Comment: e.target is DOM element that initiated the event.